# Can't drag back elements on empty dom element with double sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am starting with jquery sortable but I am having some problems understanding how it works specially when it comes to sort more than 2 different items.

Here's what I have:

http://jsbin.com/ElImEPU/2/

As you can see there I want to create 2 different sorts, one for the outter <ul>'s containing another group of <ul> and another sortable for the inner <li>'s so that I can order elements between the same category.

Problem comes when I drag the last element out of one <ul>. For some reason I can't drag back any other element so this last <ul> remains unusable.

I have read the documentation and in theory it's possible to accomplish this by adding a "connectWith" parameter but seems that I am not using it properly.

Thanks!

Comment: You should set a default `height` on the UL elements that are sortable (i.e. `min-height:20px;`). It is because your height of the UL is 0px and so can't be hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a default height on the UL elements that are sortabe (i.e. `min-height:5px;`).

The error is occuring because when the UL is empty it has a height of 0px, by setting the default you ensure it has at least some height.

```
.ui-sortable {
    min-height:5px;
}
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/fwV2w/)